# Styled-jsx typescript error after migrating to monorepo structure. Property 'jsx' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, monorepo, styled-jsx

I am using styled-jsx in my project and I just migrated it to a monorepo structure, and since then I have been having the following problem:

```
   Type '{ children: string; jsx: true; }' is not assignable to type 
   'DetailedHTMLProps<StyleHTMLAttributes<HTMLStyleElement>, HTMLStyleElement>'.
   Property 'jsx' does not exist on type 
   'DetailedHTMLProps<StyleHTMLAttributes<HTMLStyleElement>, HTMLStyleElement>'.ts(2322)
```

This appears under the jsx attribute every time I use the default tag for style-jsx:

```
    <style jsx>
        {`...`}
    </style>
```

I found a [closed issue](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/90) about this subject, and according to this [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/compare/master...timsuchanek:patch-1), this issue can be solved if I manually add the following two lines to `interface HTMLAttributes` in `react/index.d.ts`:

```
    jsx?: boolean;
    global?: boolean;
```

This actually solved the problem, but I don't want to manually modify a file from `node_modules`.

According to this [closed issue](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/90) in vercel, I should be able to fix this by simply running `yarn add -D @types/styled-jsx`, but this didn't work.

Installing the packages using using npm instead of yarn fixed the problem too, but I don't want to change the package manager I am using. Furthermore, installing this one package with npm and the others with yarn crashed the application.

I thought this could be a hoisting problem related to `styled-jsx` and yarn workspaces, but adding

```
    "private": true,
    "nohoist":["**/styled-jsx","**/styled-jsx/**"]
```

to my root package.json and to the package.json of the project that uses styled-jsx didn't fix the problem either.

Does any one have a solution to this problem that does not involve manually modifying `react/index.d.ts`, changing my package manager or abandoning the monorepo structure?

The `package.json` of the project that uses `styled-jsx`:

```
    {
    "name": "with-typescript",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "type-check": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint **/**",
    "lint:fix": "eslint **/** --fix",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --passWithNoTests --watch",
    "test:ci": "NODE_ENV=test jest --passWithNoTests"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@types/styled-jsx": "^2.2.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "^25.2.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "next": "^10.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-jsx": "^3.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/formidable": "^1.0.32",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-jsx": "^2.2.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "typescript": "3.7.3"
    },
    "license": "ISC"
    }
```

The `package.json` of my root folder:

```
    {
    "name": "next_shsc",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "private":true,
    "repository": "https://github.com/agaragon/next_shsc.git",
    "author": "aragon <andregaragon@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "workspaces":{
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ]
    }
    }
```

Comment: update the react & @types/react with matched version may resolve this issue

Answer (score 16):

This solution fixed the issue for me (after [@smeijer at GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/90#issuecomment-318052994)):

Create a *TypeScript Declaration File*, named e.g. `custom.d.ts`:

```
import 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface StyleHTMLAttributes<T> extends React.HTMLAttributes<T> {
    jsx?: boolean;
    global?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Place it somewhere in the project, for example in the `/src/typings` folder. It should be picked up by the compiler automatically, but it may possibly depend on the config (?).

If you get `eslint` error complaining about the `import 'react'` line, put the following comment above it:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react/no-typos`
```

Comment: I stumbled across an error with jsx prop in <style> and this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Installing the `@types/styled-jsx` package didn't work for me - it's a stub for the types, as `styled-jsx` includes their own now.

Reading the docs on the styled-jsx github, there's a specific solution for this: https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#typescript

Adding a file at the root of my next app named `styled-jsx.d.ts` and putting this in it worked for me:

`/// <reference types="styled-jsx" />`

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Next 12.1.6` and I had this problem until I installed `@types/styled-jsx 3.4.4`.

I think it is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pnpm 7` in a monorepo and `Next 12.2.0` I had to install `styled-jsx` in my app with `pnpm add styled-jsx`